# Discord Music Bot won't play music

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord music bot by scratch, it won't play music, but it will connect.

here is the code if you wanna look at it:
https://pastebin.com/vFeW4bWN

```
    @app_commands.command()
    @app_commands.describe(url='The Youtube Video Link')
    async def play(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, *, url: str):
        # Get the voice channel the user is in
        User = interaction.user.voice.channel.id
        UserChannel = interaction.client.get_channel(User)
        # Check if user is in a voice channel
        if UserChannel is not None:
            # Join the voice channel
            await UserChannel.connect()
            # Stream the song
            async with interaction.channel.typing():
                player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
                interaction.guild.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error {e}') if e else None)
            
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Now Playing {player.title} Suga!')
        # if User is not in Voice Channel, tells user to get into voice channel
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message('You have to be in a voice channel to use me!')
```

according to the discord.py documentation, is that Voice_Client should have a play option but it does not seem to be working and I can't find another way to play audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could get author's channel by `channel = interaction.user.voice.channel`
Second, you can get your `voice_client` by `voice = await channel.connect()`
Then, you could do `voice.play(...)`. And don't forget to install ffmpeg if you want to use it to play music.